# subsetting from an bigstatsr::FBM object for LDpred2 R-tutorial

Tags: r, bigstatsr

I'm using LDpred2 incorporated in bigsnpr to calculate polygenic scores with my own set of genetic Data. I am following the steps found in the online tutorial of LDpred2 on Github (https://privefl.github.io/bigsnpr/articles/LDpred2.html) to use the automatic model `snp_ldpred2_auto`.
I cannot execute the line:

```
pred_auto <- big_prodMat(G, beta_auto, ind.row = ind.test, ind.col = df_beta[["_NUM_ID_"]])
```

I suspect this happens because the matrices are not fit for multiplication with each other since the number of columns in  `G`  (the FBM matrix) is not identical as the number of rows in  `beta_auto`  (a common matrix). I intend to filter out variants (SNPs) from `G`  such that the number of variants in  `G`  equals the number of variants in `beta_auto` .
I have never worked before with matrices of class FBM.code256 and do not know how to achieve this subsetting. Guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `ind.col` refers to the column indices of `G` that corresponds to the rows of `beta_auto`.
Also, if you have questions about {bigsnpr} (which is a rather specific package), prefer opening an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: "I cannot execute the line" -> please provide the error message, or explain what went wront.

Comment: I get the following message: "Error: You can't have missing values in 'X'."

Comment: in my case length(ind.col) = 423242; dim(beta_auto) = 423242x30; and dim(G) = 528x492469

Comment: Yes, so the error has nothing to do with dimensions. The problem is that you have missing values in `G`. You can look at https://github.com/privefl/bigsnpr/issues/49.